# What is the difference between System Testing and Integrated Testing?

Tags: testing

Want to understand the difference between System and Integration Testing.
Are they both same? What are the key areas the testing is different. Which precedes first, Is Integration testing or System Testing. Appreciate if someone clarify in detail